# Win+W (Super+W) alternative for Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, task-management

In Lubuntu, is there an alternative for Super+W of Ubuntu?

I'd like to see all running windows in Lubuntu and be able to pick one using keyboard. I can do this using Alt+tab, but it only shows application icon and tile and not a view of the application windows.

In case the answer is Alt+Tilda, what is the command as I have remapped Alt+Tilda and I don't know the original command to use it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for skippy-xd:

https://lubuntu.me/tip-skippy/